# Show div when page contains a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello im looking to show a div based on page content. Its will go on a dynamically generated shop page. I need a notice to display upon a specific item being in the cart - eg if someone has a 'toy frog' in their cart the 'frog promo.div' needs to show.

I have been trying to adapt the following script/html for usage

any help appreciated. Dave

```
<div class="contactUs"?>contact</div>
<div class="hideThis"?>xxx</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (jQuery("div.contactUs:contains('toy frog')").length) {
    jQuery(".hideThis").css("display","none");
}
</script>
```

============================================================

Thanks all for help so far.. I know nothing about JS!

I dont think I have been clear reading through/trying all this..

What i am trying to acheve is

1**. when a product with the word 'subscrtiption' is added to my shopping cart I need a html message to show.**

I tried a few of the examples that seem to work on jsfiddle, but not on my server.. is that common?

cheers all..again

Comment: Your example is working just fine.. I dont see any `toy frog` in your div

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way round. Change "none" to "block".

Comment: And when I put `toy frog` in your div, it hides that `<div>`.

Comment: the approach seems unpleasant to me, how about creating a 'promotions' table (in the db) linked to the main items and show them in the promotions div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code sample (in relation with your problem description: cart content with product to show a promo div), but I made a [small code](http://jsbin.com/sorocugi/7/edit) to answer your problem.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--   Into your page HTML, Imagine you have two parts -->

<!--   The first one is the cart that contain the item the user want to buy -->
<div class="cart">
  *Cart*
   <div class="sausages">sausages</div>
   <!-- Try to remove comment of code following -->
   <!-- <div class="fries">fries</div> -->
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<!--   The second one is the content page that contain the div you want to display     according to item into your cart -->
<div class="content">
  *Content*
   <div class="sausages" style="display:none">sausages</div>
   <div class="fries" style="display:none">fries</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var $content = $('.content');
var $cart = $('.cart');

// for each children element (el) into my div cart  
$cart.children().each(function(index, el) {

  // I try to find a element with my className into my div Content
  // And if I find it Then I show it
  $content.find('.' + el.className).show();
});
```

I have updated [my code](http://jsbin.com/sorocugi/7/edit) with comments to be clearer

Comment: Hi Frédéric
Thanks for taking the time on this!
I dont understand JS at all, so its pretty tricky for me.. When I look at you e.g. I dont get how to make it do what I want! I want a hidden div to appear on a page if it contains a word, say 'sausages' and hide if it does not.. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if( $('.contactUs').is(':empty') ) {
  // ...
```

Or you could just test the length property to see if one was found:

```
if( $('.contactUs:empty').length ) {
   // ...
```

Keep in mind that empty means no what space either. If there's a chance that there will be white space, then you can use $.trim() and check for the length of the content.

```
if( !$.trim( $('.contactUs').html() ).length ) {
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactDivText = $('.contactUs').text();
var hideDiv = $('.hideThis');
if(contactDivText == ''){
    hideDiv.hide();
}else{
    hideDiv.text(contactDivText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!
I know nothing about javascript and was just trying to hack at the code until it worked!

I have tried your solution as below, but still no luck! Where am i going wrong??

<div class="contactUs"?>test</div>
<div class="hideThis"?>this should appear if test is in contactUs div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var contactDivText = $('.contactUs').text();
var hideDiv = $('.hideThis');
if(contactDivText == 'test'){
    hideDiv.hide();
}else{
    hideDiv.text(contactDivText);
}
</script>

Comment: I think its your question marks inside the div which do not belong there. Should be: <div class="contactUs"></div>. Check the link below. On that site (top left box) is your html. When you replace the word 'test' and hit 'run' in top-menu then the red box appears again otherwise it is hidden

Comment: Thanks Hobby
is there any reason why this wouldn't run on my server?
if i put it on a page 
http://www.bee-craft.com/showdiv/wordonpageshowdiv.htm it doesnt work the same! Sorry complete newbie

Comment: do you get any jquery to work? Test this with: <script>$(function(){alert('are you working?')})</script>  Does that make an alert box to pop up?

Comment: if not then include <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> inside your <head></head>